# Stop a timer from outside a jvm

Tags: java

I have a long running timer task. Its a batch process actually that will keep looping forever and working its stuff. This batch program is written in Java. Now how do I ask it to gracefully shutdown if for example I need to do some maintenance?  From outside the JVM?

I could think of some dirty ways, at the end of every loop of the run method, have it check for the presence of a file in some directory. If it is present then it will stop. Or create a database record asking it to stop.

Is there another better way of doing this?

Comment: a configuration file doesn't seem too dirty to me, but it depends who has to do this, a techie or your customer?

Comment: You mean you've got both a Java program running and a batch running and you want to stop the batch when the Java program exits, because of maintenance, for example? (otherwise why would this be flagged with the 'Java' tag? ; )   One way you can use is to have your Java program be launched with a "magic number" and have your batch file, in its main loop, check that the Java program with the corresponding magic number is still running (you'd first pass the magic number to the batch of course).  Another way would be to take the PIDs of the batch you created and send them a signal when you exit.

Comment: @sethu: the "dirty way" of having the batch check for a file mean you'd need to create the file (from your Java program right?).  I typically go with the "magic number" which uniquely identifies this specific run of my Java program.  This way I'm not "polluting" anything nor messing with anything and should the Java program abruptly exit, the batch will gracefully exit too (because the batch shall notice the unique Java program that started the batch isn't running anymore). The "magic number" is just a random string passed as an arg to the Java program, like *java -jar ex.jar A093BC3F32D8712*

Comment: @sethu: *"no it will be me"* <-- but then why is this question even tagged with 'Java' !?   : )     It is the Java program itself that you want stop gracefully?  Or the batch process(es) it spawns?  Or both?

Comment: @user988052 - There is only one java program. That is what I am referring to as the  'batch program'. Its in the batch java program where a timer is running in a never ending loop. How do I stop this java program from outside the jvm?

Comment: @sethu: oh OK, I thought you were asking about something else: I thought you had a Java program and that that Java program was spawning one or more batch processes, not the other way round : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a graceful shutdown the service will have to check something periodically. It could be end (or beginning) of every loop or less frequent. So I think your approach is correct.

Checking for the presence of a file can be good way to do it. Having to delete the file could get tedious -- one option is for the method itself to delete the file before exiting.

Other option is to run some socket listener as part of your application. There may be security issues though.

Answer (score 5):

You may want add support for MBeans to your program and send commands to it through jconsole.

Here are MBeans links:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions

Comment: +1 this looks like the proper way, but honestly, would it be hard to implement?

Comment: @stivlo. If the application uses spring, then it may be not that hard -> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jmx.html

Comment: I don't know sethu, but I'm using Spring, I'll try it when I finish this project I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: Voted up cause I know thats the right way.. but it looks a little involved for me to work with at the moment. Need to understand how to use it first. Will go with the file creation approach for now and then switch to this later I think.. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

you can add a [shut-down hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) that will run when you kill the process (through task manager) to cleanly shut down

```
Runtime.getRunTime().addShutDownHook(new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //do shutdown (interrupt threads and tell them to shut down)
    }
});
```

Comment: +1. In Linux it would work perfectly, however, discerning from OP's use of terms like `batch` I suspect it's running in Windows. And on Windows (from my experience), when you Ctrl-C console program it does not run the shutdown hook but instead simply kills the process.